# Get "As low as" price for bundle product in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to display a list of bundled products using my custom template. I'm not able to display the dynamic price of the bundle product. Previously for simple products I used:

```
$product->getPrice();
```

which worked, but it just displays $0.00 for bundle items.

looking at ../catalog/products/list.phtml I tried

```
$this->$getPriceHtml($product, true);
```

after extending my block to Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract I got simple products working again, but bundle products still show $0.00

Is there another way to display the as low as price for dynamic bundle prices?

I cleared cache and reindexed and all that good stuff. The price shows up correctly under the default category list, just not under my custom page.

**Update**

I haven't been able to figure out an alternative. When I did a dump of the product collection, for the bundle product fields containing prices are as follows:

```
["price_type"] => string(1) "0"

["price_view"] => string(1) "0"
  ["_price_index"] => bool(true)
    ["_price_index_min_price"] => string(8) "475.0000"
    ["_price_index_max_price"] => string(8) "475.0000"
    ["tax_percent"] => float(9)
    ["final_price"] => int(0)
```

For simple products I only get:

```
["price"] => string(8) "248.0000"
 ["final_price"] => string(8) "248.0000"
```

so I suppose I could write my own function to grab the price depending on product type, but I'm guessing there's a better way...

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I'm using 1.3.2, but would eventually like to start getting into 1.4 as well.
Also today, I added a bundle product to our sale products block (which was added by someone else) and I noticed the same problem. Bundle products display as $0.00.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: well i've been looking at some other aspects of bundled products and realized that bundled products pricing is generated completely separate from simple and grouped products.

Comment: @dardub, have you found a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: @Geoffrey - I've actually moved away from Magento, there are much better solutions out there that are easier to customize and maintain. When you simply look at a list of features; nothing can beat Magento, but in terms of actual use, it's terrible.

Answer (score 1):

look at /app/design/frontend/base/deafault/layout/bundle.xml

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

you should add your custom phtml (no control needed xml does that). Start from your bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml to get all function you need ;) good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use my magento module:

https://github.com/head82/KH_ExtendedBundlePrice